How use localVue in test?
I use Quasar and vue test utils. Try to test component with Quasar components like q-btn and etc.
Vue component:
<template>
...
  <q-btn
     data-test="deleteBtn"
     @click="deleteAlphabet(index)">
     :disabled="index === 0"
     delete item
  </q-btn>
...
</template>
<script>
...
    deleteAlphabet(alphabetIndex) {
      this.alphabetsList = this.alphabetsList.filter((i, index) => index !== alphabetIndex)
    },
</script>

Test:
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import DialogPasswordRequirements from 'src/components/dialogs/DialogPasswordRequirements.vue'
import  * as All from 'quasar'
const { Quasar } = All

const wrapper = mount(
  DialogPasswordRequirements,
  {
  data () {
    return {
      alphabetsList: [
        {
         symbols: 'abc',
         min: 1,
         hint: '[abc]'
       },
       {
         symbols: 'abc',
         min: 1,
         hint: '[abc]'
       }
     ]
    }
  },
  }
)
...
it ('Checking for impossibility of deleting the last item', async () => {
  const deleteBtn = wrapper.find('[data-test="deleteBtn"]')
  expect(deleteBtn.exists()).toBe(true)
  const counter = clone(wrapper.vm.items.length)
  for (let i=0; i<counter; i++) {
    await deleteBtn.trigger('click')
}
  expect(wrapper.vm.alphabetsList.length).not.toBe(0)
})

Using the method above all works. Before for loop wrapper.vm.alphabetsList.length is 2. After for loop (deleting) it's also 1. but I get console errors like:
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <q-input> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
If I use below method with localVue and use components:
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import DialogPasswordRequirements from 'src/components/dialogs/DialogPasswordRequirements.vue'
import  * as All from 'quasar'
import { clone } from 'lodash'
const { Quasar } = All

const components = Object.keys(All).reduce((object, key) => {
  const val = All[key]
  if (val && val.component && val.component.name != null) {
    object[key] = val
  }
  return object
}, {})

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Quasar, { components })

const wrapper = shallowMount(
  DialogPasswordRequirements,
  {
    localVue,
  data () {
    return {
      alphabetsList: [
        {
         symbols: 'abc',
         min: 1,
         hint: '[abc]'
       },
       {
         symbols: 'abc',
         min: 1,
         hint: '[abc]'
       }
     ]
    }
  },
  }
)
...
it ('Checking for impossibility of deleting the last item', async () => {
  const deleteBtn = wrapper.find('[data-test="deleteBtn"]')
  expect(deleteBtn.exists()).toBe(true)
  const counter = clone(wrapper.vm.items.length)
  for (let i=0; i<counter; i++) {
    await deleteBtn.trigger('click')
}
  expect(wrapper.vm.alphabetsList.length).not.toBe(0)
})

data in tests after triggering click does not change. Before for loop wrapper.vm.alphabetsList.length is 2. After for loop (deleting) it's also 2.
I tried to test component by 2 ways. I expect success test without errors. What I should change?

The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's not shown why deleteBtn is expected to exist. Did you try to debug wrapper.html()? Currently only you can do this
